# disabling the data from dropdown when same data we typed in input field with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

How can I write a jQuery function that disables the value from dropdown only if same data we typed in input field.

Input Field - NEW

So from drop down new should be disabled.

```
<select class="form-control" id="select2">
   <option value="1">New</option>
   <option value="2">OLD</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just to note: There is no Spring or Thymeleaf in this question. Those tags are irrelevant and can be removed. You can [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.typeVal').on("keyup change",function() {
  var $val = $(this).val();
  $('#select2 option').prop("disabled", function() {
    return $(this).text() == $val;
  });
});
```

This code is using jQuery to bind an event handler to elements with the class .typeVal. The event handler will be triggered on "keyup" and "change" events on these elements.

When the event is triggered, the code gets the value of the element that triggered the event and stores it in a variable $val. Then, it sets the "disabled" property of all the  elements within the #select2 element based on a function.

The function returns true if the text content of the  element is equal to $val, meaning it will disable the  if it has the same text content as the triggering element. If the text content of the  is not equal to $val, the function returns false and the  will not be disabled.

**Demo**

```js
$('.typeVal').on("keyup change",function() {
  var $val = $(this).val();
  $('#select2 option').prop("disabled", function() {
    return $(this).text() == $val;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="typeVal" />

<select class="form-control" id="select2">
  <option value="1">New</option>
  <option value="2">OLD</option>
</select>
```